# Create reference of custom cell in function and update Label in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to use the custom cell in function when button is clicked. and update a label in that specific row using the function.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CardCell

cell.startcount.tag = indexPath.row
                cell.startcount.addTarget(self, action: "startcount:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

}
```

here is the function I'm using

```
func startcount(sender: AnyObject){

// create a reference of  CardCell
// update the counter like cell.textcount.text = "\(counter)"
// in the specific row

    }
```

My custom cell class :

```
import UIKit

class CardCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textcount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startcount: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func startcount(sender: AnyObject){
    let button = sender as UIButton
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:button.tag inSection:0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CardCell

    // update cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 4 and above**

```
func startCount(sender : AnyObject) {
    let button = sender as! UIButton
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row:button.tag ,section:0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CardCell
    // update cell
}
```